# flutter app not loading properly after releasing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

VS Code Build Output.:

[image: VS Code Output]

App Output without problem:

[image: Final App Image]

App after some time:

this happens when I close and open app for 2 or 3 times:

[image: Error in App Image]

If anybody can solve this problem please help me.

Comment: Check whether your photo paths are correct or not.

Comment: Try this command -> (flutter build apk --no-shrink)
Then you have to install the app manually.

Comment: `flutter build apk --no-shrink` Not Working Same Problem  going on